# powershell create apps group in metroUI

Tags: powershell, windows-8, startmenu

I need to create folder in metroUI in separate group.
I can do this manually like [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/122446/organize-tiles-into-groups-on-the-metro-start-screen-in-windows-8/), but I have to do this with powershell.
Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Export-StartLayout, modify the XML and then use Import-StartLayout

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn283401(v=wps.630).aspx